# Google Sheets combine several sheets into one sheet with script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to combine several sheets into one sheet with script. Also, when combining sheets I need to separate them by checking their names in to two columns. For example sheets which contain a word "cat" should be on the left column and sheets which contain a word "dog" should be on the right column. Currently, I have a script which filters all sheets with a specific words to one array. I am new to Google Sheets, any help will be appreciated.

Here is my current script:

```
function myFunction() 
 {
 var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("AllSheets");

if (newSheet != null) {
    activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSheet);
}

newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
newSheet.setName("AllSheets");
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const allSheets = ss.getSheets();
   const allSheets_names=allSheets.map(sheet=>sheet.getSheetName())  

   const neededSheets= ["Cat", "Dog"];
   
   const filteredListOfSheetsNames = []   
   neededSheets.forEach(ns =>allSheets_names.forEach( (as,index) =>
       {if (as.indexOf(ns)>-1){filteredListOfSheetsNames.push(as)}}))                   
       const filteredListOfSheets =  filteredListOfSheetsNames.map(name =>ss.getSheetByName(name))  
           
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about your current situation and goal. So in order to correctly understand about them, can you provide the sample input and output you expect? And also, can you provide your current script? If you can do them, can you add them to your question? By this, I would like to try to understand them.

Comment: @Tanaike Let me apologize for not explaining it better. I have edited my question.

Comment: So do your sheets contain only one column? Would you mind to provide a screenshot of what the data in your sheets looks like? And what you want it to like like in the cmbined sheet?

Comment: @ziganotschka i have added a screenshot on how it should look like on the right side. The left side is a one sheet of the cat.

Comment: I can see only a single sheet in the screenshot. Do all your sheets contain the same (maximum) number of columns (e.g. 4), so in the final sheet the information from cat sheets shall be in columns A to D andthe one from dog sheets in columns E to H? You need to specify the start column for "dog" in the final sheet  to avoid overwriting.

Comment: @ziganotschka to be clear, the sheets with cat and dog should have 13 columns each, cat should have 10 rows and dog should have 9 rows. There are a lot of different sheets, some of them contain word dog and some of the contain a word cat. They all have same amount of columns and rows 10 or 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The best is to create two arrays - for two different ranges of the summary sheet

- To one you append the "Cat sheets", to the other the "Dog sheets"
- Since you already found and sorted your sheets of interest correctly, within your inner loop you can define an auxiliary array (a separate one for each type of sheets) to which you append the data from all the sheets of one type
- Set this array to the desired range (side) of the destination sheet
- It is important to know the (maximum) dimensions of the origin sheets to divide the lest/right sides of the destinations sheet correctly.

Sample:

```js
function myFunction() 
{
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("AllSheets");  
  if (newSheet != null) {
    activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSheet);
  }  
  newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
  newSheet.setName("AllSheets");
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  const allSheets_names=allSheets.map(sheet=>sheet.getSheetName())    
  const neededSheets= ["Cat", "Dog"];  
  const filteredListOfSheetsNames = [];       
  neededSheets.forEach(function(ns){  
    var i = neededSheets.indexOf(ns);
    filteredListOfSheetsNames[i]=[];
    allSheets_names.forEach( (as,index) => {                            
      if (as.indexOf(ns)>-1){
        filteredListOfSheetsNames[i].push(as);
        }
      }
    )
    const filteredListOfSheets  =  filteredListOfSheetsNames[i].map(name =>ss.getSheetByName(name));  
    var array = [];
    filteredListOfSheets.forEach(function(sheet){var values = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),13).getValues(); array.push(values);});
    array = [].concat.apply([],array);
    if(array.length > 0){
      newSheet.getRange(1,i*13+1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I am getting a TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line 34, file "Code"). This is the line of     newSheet.getRange(1,i*13+1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);. I am not sure how to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you have at least one sheet of each type (mind the case sensitivity) and that at lesat one of those sheets is not empty)? If not, you should implement an `if statement to account for those cases, I will update my answer. Implement some logs in the code to see either sheets and data have been found correctly.

Comment: I am very sorry I have miss typed the neededSheets, everything is working great! Thank you very much! Also, may I ask how I can keep the styles of the sheets? For example colours, font? And lastly, how can I make empty rows between the sheets so It would be more readable? Once more, thank you a lot!

Comment: To insert an empty row, you can implement after `array.push(values);` the request `array.push([[ ]])`To keep the styles, you would need to proceed differently and use the method [CopyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed) instead of `setValues()`. This would make the workflow diffrent, so I suggest you to ask it as a new question - have a try first to implement it yourself as far as you get.