# Google Sheets separating sheets while combining

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to combine sheets which have a word "dog" or a word "cat" in them. Currently, I have a script which filters sheets with these names and merges them into one sheet. The issue now is that I want to list all sheets with a name of "dog" on the left side of the mainsheet and the sheets with the name "cat" on the right side of the mainsheet, it should look like two columns of different sheets in the mainsheet. I would like to also create an empty row after each sheet, so it would be more readable. All my sheets have 13 columns (dog sheets have 10 rows, cat sheets have 9 rows). Currently, everything is being mashed together. Here is my current script:

```
function myFunction() 
 {
   var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("MainSheet");
   
   if (newSheet != null) {
        activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSheet);
    }

   newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
   newSheet.setName("MainSheet");
   
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const allSheets = ss.getSheets();
   const allSheets_names=allSheets.map(sheet=>sheet.getSheetName())  
   const dataRange = "A1:M";
   const checkRange = "A1:A";
   const neededSheets= ["Dogs", "Cats"];
   
   const filteredListOfSheetsNames = []   
   neededSheets.forEach(ns =>allSheets_names.forEach( (as,index) =>
       {if (as.indexOf(ns)>-1){filteredListOfSheetsNames.push(as)}}))                   
   const filteredListOfSheets =  filteredListOfSheetsNames.map(name =>ss.getSheetByName(name))  
   let formulaArray = filteredListOfSheets.map(s => `FILTER({'${s.getSheetName()}'!${dataRange}},'${s.getSheetName()}' !${checkRange}<>"")`);
   let formulaText = "={" + formulaArray.join(";") + "}";
   ss.getSheetByName("MainSheet").getRange("A1").setFormula(formulaText);

}
```

May I ask if someone knows how to order those sheets based by the names to the left and the right side of the mainsheet?
Any help will be appreciated.
This is how the main sheet should look like, on one side the different sheets with cats and on another side different sheet with dogs, also I would like to make spaces between sheets so it would be more readable. I would like to query the data by formula.

[image: This is how the main sheet should look like, on one side the different sheets with cats and on another side different sheet with dogs, also I would like to make spaces between sheets so it would be more readable]

Comment: I see in your code you are using formulas . Do you want the data to be queried by a formula or hard copy via script ? Also a copy of your sheet with sample data will help us understand what will be the expected output.

Comment: @Marios Hello, I have updated my question. I would like to query the data by a formula.

Comment: Did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63621801/google-sheets-combine-several-sheets-into-one-sheet-with-script/63633213?noredirect=1#comment112524540_63633213 solve your quesiton or is there still another issue you experince?

Comment: @ziganotschka It did, thank you very much! I have also added a comment about a certain thing in that question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets combine several sheets into one sheet with script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63621801/google-sheets-combine-several-sheets-into-one-sheet-with-script)

Comment: @Rubén it did, thank you!